# JqGrid Reload not working

Tags: php, jqgrid

I'm having an issue with Jqgrid, I've got two grids on a single page and onclick on a row of the first grid needs to reload the second grid.

I'm 100% sure the second grid is configured correctly is if I manually pass a hard coded id it populates correctly.

Just the reload function is not working. Please could someone assist. Below is the jquery code for both grids

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid({ 
        url:'classes/ListServices.php', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST', 
        colNames: ['Id','Description', 'Details', 'Cost in (R)'], 
        colModel: [ 
            {name:'Id',index:'Id', align:"center", width:30}, 
            {name:'Description',index:'Description', align:"center"}, 
            {name:'Details',index:'Details', align:"left"}, 
            {name:'Cost',index:'Cost',align:"center",width:30,formatter:'currency'},
        ],
        width: 780,
        height: 100, 
        rowNum:18, 
        pager: '#pager1',
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc", 
        caption:"Services List",
        multiselect: false,
        onSelectRow: function(ids) {
            if(ids == null) { 
                ids=0; 
                if(jQuery("#list3").jqGrid('getGridParam','records') >0 ) {
                    jQuery("#list3").jqGrid('setGridParam',
                                           {url:"subgrid.php?q=1&id="+ids,page:1});
                    jQuery("#list3").jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid'); 
                } 
            } 
            else { 
                jQuery("#list3").jqGrid('setGridParam',
                                        {url:"subgrid.php?q=1&id="+ids,page:1}); 
                jQuery("#list3").jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid'); 
            }       
        }  
    }); 

    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',
                            {edit:false,add:false,del:false,multipleSearch:true});
    jQuery("#list2").jqGrid('filterToolbar',
                            {stringResult: true,searchOnEnter : false});

    jQuery("#list3").jqGrid({ 
        url:'classes/ListServicesDetails.php?Id=2', 
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: 'POST', 
        colNames: ['Id','ServiceId', 'Description', 'Details', 'Cost in (R)'], 
        colModel: [ 
           {name:'Id',index:'Id', align:"center", width:30},
           {name:'ServiceId',index:'ServiceId', align:"center", width:30},  
           {name:'Description',index:'Description', align:"center"}, 
           {name:'Details',index:'Details', align:"left"}, 
           {name:'Cost',index:'Cost',align:"center",width:30,formatter:'currency'},
        ],
        width: 780,
        height: 200, 
        rowNum:18, 
        pager: '#pager2',
        loadonce: true,
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc", 
        caption:"Services Details List",
        multiselect: false,
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
            alert(id);
        }  
    }); 
    jQuery("#list3").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager2',
                            {edit:false,add:false,del:false,multipleSearch:true});
});
```

Please if someone could assist me ...

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

Both jqGrids has parameters `loadonce: true`. It means that after the first loading the `datatype` of the grids will be changed from `"json"` to `"local"`. To reload the second grid you should reset the `datatype` parameter to `"json"` together with `url` and `page` parameters.

Comment: Hi there Oleg,

Thanks a million - works 100%.
If i haven't said it before - This Forum Rocks!

Thanks

Comment: this worked for me as well and i didnt need to set the url or page params either, thanks!

Comment: @Will: You welcome! The setting of the url before `jqGrid.trigger('reloadGrid')` is specific for the question, but the setting of `page:1` is recommended in the most cases. The reason is following. Let us the user choosed the page number 5 before data refreshing and after reload the total number of pages will be 4. If you don't reset `page` the user can see an empty page 5 after refreshing and will not understand the reason of this. To have this problem no time you can set `page:1` before `reloadGrid`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014