# Inserting markup into hidden jqGrid column

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Got jqGrid up and running nicely where I've got a hidden field that contains some markup, just a table of data, and when I hover over a grid row the markup for the hidden column in that row appears in a tooltip. I want to be able to duplicate grid items and in doing so I want to clear the grid and repopulate with only the duplicated records and the original.

Unfortunately, i'm getting this issue when reloading the grid:

```
Message: 's.grid.headers[...].width' is null or not an object
Line: 91
Char: 390
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost:51325/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js
```

Here's my grid definition:

```
$('#RequestGrid').jqGrid({
    url: GetUrl(),
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'POST',
    colNames: ['ID', 'AOM', 'Start Date', 'End Date', 'Coordinator 1', 'Coordinator 2', 'Driver?', 'Status', 'Assigned To', 'RequestHours'],
    colModel: [
        { name: 'ResourceRequestID', index: 'ResourceRequestID', width: 20, key: true },
        { name: 'AOM', index: 'AOM.Surname', width: 70 },
        { name: 'StartDate', index: 'StartDate', width: 50 },
        { name: 'EndDate', index: 'EndDate', width: 50 },
        { name: 'Coordinator1', index: 'Coordinator.Surname', width: 60 },
        { name: 'Coordinator2', index: 'Coordinator1.Surname', width: 60 },
        { name: 'DriverPreference', index: 'DriverPreference.Description', width: 40 },
        { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', sortable: false, width: 40 },
        { name: 'AssignedResourceID', index: 'AssignedResourceID', width: 50 },
        { name: 'RequestHours', index: 'RequestHours', hidden: true }
    ],
    ...
    loadui: 'block',
    width: 750,
    ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol) {
        window.location = '/Request/Edit/' + rowid;
    },                
    gridComplete: function() {
        $("tr.jqgrow").mouseover(function(e) {
            var requestHours = $(this).find('td').eq(9).html();
            $(this).tipTip({ activation: "hover", edgeOffset: 5, content: requestHours, keepAlive: false, fadeIn: 0, maxWidth: "250px" });
        });
    }
});
```

The markup for the hidden field is built in my controller as below:

```
public string BuildRequestPlan(ResourceRequest req)
{
    string requestPlan = "<p>Request #" + req.ResourceRequestID.ToString() + "</p>";
    requestPlan += "<p>Location: " + req.Location.LocationName + "</p>";
    requestPlan += "<table id=toolTipAvailability><tr><td>Day</td><td>8-9</td><td>9-10</td><td>10-11</td><td>11-12</td><td>12-1</td><td>1-2</td><td>2-3</td><td>3-4</td><td>4-5</td><td>5-6</td><td>6-7</td><td>7-8</td><td>8-9</td><td>9-10</td><td>O/S</td></tr>";

    string[] days = { "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun" };
    int[] hrs = { 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22 };

    for (int day = 1; day <= days.Length; day++)
    {
        requestPlan += "<tr><td oncontextmenu=return false;>" + days[day - 1] + "</td>";

        for (int hour = 8; hour < 23; hour++)
        {
            requestPlan += "<td class=toolTipAvailabilityCell day=" + day + " hour=" + hour + ">";

            var requestHour = req.RequestHours.SingleOrDefault(h => h.Hour == hour && h.WeekDay == day);

            if (requestHour != null)
            {
                requestPlan += requestHour.Minutes.ToString();
            }

            requestPlan += "</td>";
        }

        requestPlan += "</tr>";
    }

    requestPlan += "</table>";

    return requestPlan;
}
```

This method is called for each item in the list of duplicates:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Duplicate(int cloneRequestID, int cloneCount)
{
    ResourceRequest resourceRequest = this._resourceRequestService.GetByID(cloneRequestID);

    // get the assignedResourceID of resourceRequest to clone
    int? assignedResourceID = resourceRequest.AssignedResourceID;

    // nullify the assignedResourceID
    resourceRequest.AssignedResourceID = null;

    List<ResourceRequest> clones = new List<ResourceRequest>();

    for (int i = 0; i < cloneCount; i++)
    {
        ResourceRequest temp = (ResourceRequest)resourceRequest.Clone();
        this._resourceRequestService.Add(temp);
        clones.Add(temp);
    }

    // reinstate the assignedResourceID
    resourceRequest.AssignedResourceID = assignedResourceID;

    // add original erquest to clones collection
    clones.Add(resourceRequest);

    try
    {
        this._unitOfWork.Commit();
        int totalRecords = clones.Count();
        int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)10);

        var jsonData = from req in clones
            select new
            {
                ResourceRequestID = req.ResourceRequestID.ToString(),
                AOM = string.Format("{0}, {1}", req.AOM.Surname, req.AOM.Forename),
                StartDate = req.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                EndDate = req.EndDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"),
                Coordinator1 = string.Format("{0}, {1}", req.Coordinator.Surname, req.Coordinator.Forename),
                Coordinator2 = req.SecondCoordinatorID == null ? "N/A" : string.Format("{0}, {1}", req.Coordinator1.Surname, req.Coordinator1.Forename),
                DriverPreference = req.DriverPreference.Description,
                Status = req.RequestCancelledDate.HasValue ? "Cancelled" : req.AssignedResourceID.HasValue ? "Assigned" : "Unassigned",
                AssignedResourceID = req.Resource == null ? "N/A" : req.Resource.Employee.FullName,
                RequestHours = BuildRequestPlan(req)
            };

        return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonData));             
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        var data = new { error = e.Message };

        return Json(data);
    }
}
```

This is how I rebind the grid:

```
$.post('/Request/Duplicate', { cloneRequestID: $('#cloneRequestID').val(), cloneCount: $('#cloneCount').val() }, function (data) {

    $('#RequestGrid').clearGridData(true);

    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);

    $('#RequestGrid').addRowData('ResourceRequestID', jsonData);
});
```

I tried returning just an empty table e.g. `<table><tr></tr></table>` and it worked but when I added an empty cell it stopped working so something is going wrong with the markup.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue? Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Could you pleae explain **WHY** you need to duplicate the grid instead of refreshing the grid or filing new grid one more time?

Comment: Hi Oleg, I am just refreshing the grid by clearing it and manually inserting the original record and the duplicates. After this the grid can be refreshed to show all records. The idea is to give a quick summary of what record was duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this issue by wrapping a HTML comment around the markup in the BuildRequestPlan method. When it comes to passing the markup to the tooltip I just strip out the comments. It's unorthodox but it works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would be recommend you to use [userdata](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#user_data) to save and additional information to the jqGrid. The data saved in [userdata](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#user_data) can be absolutely free. It can be for example an array with you HTML code fragments or an object with `ResourceRequestID` values as properties and the corresponding HTML code fragments as the value. So with `jQuery("RequestGrid").getGridParam('userData')` you can get the reference to the data any time and with `userData` parameter you can set the data directly for a new jqGrid.

The main advantage of the usage of `userData` is that the data will be not placed somewhere as a part of HTML code like you do this now. So the data will be not encoded in any way and it can have any contain without restrictions.

If you want to refresh the data in jqGrid you can either just use `jQuery("RequestGrid").trigger("reloadGrid")` or get the grid data with `jQuery("RequestGrid").getGridParam('data')`, then create new grid with `data` as a parameter and `datatype: 'local'`. Then you can change `datatype` from `'local'` to `'json'` after the grid is created (if you really want to have `'json'` and not `'local'` grid). It can be a simple way to duplicate the data. Moreover, I am not sure, but probably the usage of `loadone: true` can be interesting for you (look at [JqGrid Reload not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441839/jqgrid-reload-not-working) if you decide to use this).