# How to get jqGrid reload to go to server?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, navigator

We use the jqGrid navigator reload button on a grid with `loadonce` set to true.

The reload button currently does NOT go back to the server to get the data - how can we get the reload to go to the server to get the latest data?

I believe we can use the [`beforeRefresh`](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator) callback to set the grid `data` to `json` instead of `local` but I'm not clear how to even configure the `beforeRefresh` method - I don't really understand the docs.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You are not the only person which has the problem. I answerd to [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441839/jqgrid-reload-not-working/3442156#3442156) before. To reload the grid content from the server you should reset the `datatype` parameter to original value "json" or "xml" and then refresh the grid. For example

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

**UPDATED**: To call the line inside of [beforeRefresh](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters) event handler you can do following

```
jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',
  { edit:false,view:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,
    beforeRefresh: function(){
        alert('In beforeRefresh');
        grid.jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'}).trigger('reloadGrid');
    }
  });
```

I modified an example from am old question. [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/StudentGridData.htm) if you click on the refresh button you can see live how the code work.

**UPDATED 2**: [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports some new options. `reloadGrid` event supports `fromServer: true` parameter which can be used to force reloading of data from the server and `navGrid` supports `reloadGridOptions` option which can be used to specify the options of `reloadGrid` used on click on Refresh button. So the above code could be

```
$("#list").jqGrid("navGrid", {
    edit: false,
    add: false,
    del: false,
    search: false,
    reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
});
```

By the way one can use `navOptions` option of jqGrid to specify default options of `navGrid` (see the wiki article). It allows to write the code something like

```
$("#link").jqGrid({
    // all typical jqGrid parameters
    datatype: "json", // or "xml"
    loadonce: true,
    pager: true, // no empty div for page is required
    navOptions: {
        edit: false,
        add: false,
        del: false,
        search: false,
        reloadGridOptions: { fromServer: true }
    }
}).jqGrid("navGrid");
```

Comment: Thanks - How can you run this code when the reload button is clicked?  I am not clear how to configure the nav bar to execute the `beforeRefresh` method if this is what you are alluding to.

Comment: @Marcus: If is very easy. I includes the corresponding code in my answer.

Comment: @Oleg, I tried doing this, but once I click the refresh button, the pagination does not work.

Comment: @SukeshKumar: If you have problems with pagination you should probably reset `datatype` inside some other callbacks like `onPaging` for example (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9047197/315935) for an example).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following config and it works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function() {
    jq("#YOUR-GRID-ID").jqGrid({
        ...
        loadonce: true,
        ...
    });
    jQuery("#refresh_YOUR-GRID-ID").click(function(){
        jQuery("#YOUR-GRID-ID").setGridParam({datatype: 'json'});
        jQuery("#YOUR-GRID-ID").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });
});
</script>
```