# Requesting page 0 in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Is it possible to start from page=0 in a jqGrid?

I am working with data that is out of my control and when i request page 1 I actually get page 2 from the server, so therefore I am looking for some way to actually request page 0.

As far as i can see, setting the page parameter in the [jqGrid options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) to zero has no effect. When inspecting the request the page parameter is still 1.

I have also tried to change the page parameter later on after initialization. This sets the page to 1:

```
grid.setGridParam({page:0}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

This on the other hand sets page successfully to 5 in the request:

```
grid.setGridParam({page:5}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

I guess there is some check against requesting page 0 but any ideas on how to work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your problem correct you can solve it by using [serializeGridData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events) event handler and `page` property in the [jsonReader defined as function](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function).

I don't tested what you find below, but I hope either the code or a little modified code should work:

```
serializeGridData: function(postData) {
    if (typeof(ts.p.postData.page) === "number") {
        postData.page--; // decrease the value of page before sending to the server
    }
    return postData;
},
jsonReader: {
    page: function (obj) {
        return obj.page + 1; // increase the value of page returned from the server
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me! Although I changed typeof(ts.p.postData.page) to typeof(postData.page) since ts was not defined.

Wow, since I started to use jqGrid I have read sooooo many posts that you have answered Oleg. Thank you for being so dedicated towards helping people!

Comment: @Andreas: You are welcome! Thanks, I removed the `ts.p.` prefix before `postData`. Two years ago I was newcomer in web development, JavaScript, jQuery and jqGrid. Before I did software development since many years, but in other areas. So I decided to answer on the questions about jqGrid after the project where I used jqGrid was finished. I did it mostly to keep the new knowledge and expand it. After some time it become a little like my new hobby. I am glad that I could help many people. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:1}]);
```

See Oleg's reply to a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577374/jqgrid-cant-load-specific-page-during-reload-data-from-server-side).

**UPDATE**:

jqGrid pager starts from 1 and the method reloadGrid [checks](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2303) if the page is < 0, so it seems there's not much you can do.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the problem is not that i can't request and load pages 1-x but since my server is starting its paging function on page=0 I need to request page=0 for the very first page.

Comment: @Andreas: forgive me, but, wouldn't it simpler to manage that on server-side doing something like page = page - 1 ?

Comment: absolutely, that would be the best solution but it is just that i don't have easy access to the server implementation.

Comment: @Andreas: I am trying to figure out if there's a way to ovveride the javascript implementation but I guess it's not that easy.

Comment: @Andreas: I've updated my answer. the method reloadGrid in the module grid.base.js checks if you're trying to reload a page < 0 and sets it to 1. Maybe @Oleg has got a better solution than mine.