# JQuery jqgrid not sorting on client side

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

The data loads fine into the grid, but it won't sort.

When I click in the table header, the sort arrows appear, but the data's not being sorted.

Thanks.

```
    $("#CompTable").jqGrid({ 
            url:'BomExplosionInJsonObj.asp'
        ,   datatype: 'json'
        ,   mtype: 'GET'
        ,   height: 400
        ,   colNames:['Part','Description','Src','Std Usage','Usage Inc Scrap','Rate Scrap','UOM','Item','Unit Cost','Stock']
        ,   colModel:[  {name:'COMP1_PART',index:'Part', width:120}
                                ,   {name:'WSCOMPDESC',index:'Desc', width:300}
                                ,   {name:'WSCOMPSRC',index:'Src', width:10}
                                ,   {name:'COMPUSAGE',index:'Usage', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}
                                ,   {name:'WSGROSSQTY',index:'TotUsage', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}
                                ,   {name:'COMPRATE_SCRAP',index:'Rate Scrap', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}
                                ,   {name:'COMPBASIC_UNIT',index:'UOM', width:20}
                                ,   {name:'COMP1_ITEM',index:'Item', width:20}
                                ,   {name:'WSCOMPUNITCOST',index:'UnitCost', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}
                                ,   {name:'WSCOMPQTYSTOCK',index:'Stock', width:80, align:"right",sorttype:"float"}
                            ]
        ,   jsonReader: {
                root:"rows"
            ,   page: "page"
            ,   total: "total"
            ,   records: "records"
            ,   repeatitems: false
            ,   id: "0"
            }
        ,   multiselect: false
        ,   caption: "Bom Detail"
        ,   rowNum: 10000
        ,   autoencode: true
        ,   loadonce: true
        ,   sortable: true
        ,   loadComplete: function() {jQuery("#CompTable").trigger("reloadGrid");}// Call to fix client-side sorting
    });
});
```

JSON Data being returned (as read from firebug).

```
    {
     "total":"1"
    ,"page":"1"
    ,"records":"2"
    , "rows":
      [
       {"ID":1,"WSCOMPDESC":"ZYTEL E101L BLK MOUL ","WSCOMPUNITCOST":7.08,"WSCOMPSRC":"P ","WSCOMPQTYSTOCK":75,"COMPBASIC_UNIT":"KG ","COMPUSAGE":0.0034,"COMPRATE_SCRAP":0,"WSGROSSQTY":0.0034,"COMP1_PART":"1180019 ","COMP1_ITEM":" "
       },
       {"ID":2,"WSCOMPDESC":"INSERT ","WSCOMPUNITCOST":1.89,"WSCOMPSRC":"P ","WSCOMPQTYSTOCK":400,"COMPBASIC_UNIT":"EA ","COMPUSAGE":2,"COMPRATE_SCRAP":0,"WSGROSSQTY":2,"COMP1_PART":"4OWE195689\/ISS 2 ","COMP1_ITEM":" "
       }
      ]
    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You code have many important errors:

1. `colModel` contains **`index` properties which are different from the value of `name` for the same item**. It's the main bug. You don't specified any `sortname` option of jqGrid so the values of `index` properties will be never seen by the server. If you use `loadonce: true` then `index` properties must be the same as the values of `name` properties. **I recommend you don't include `index` properties at all**. In the case `index` properties will be initialized with the values of `name` properties
2. You use wrong value of `id` property in **`jsonReader`: `id: "0"`**. One use such value sometime in case of `repeatitems: true`. In the case the row will be represented in JSON input as *array*. So `0` value will be correct because in can be used as index in the array. In case of usage `repeatitems: false` the items represented rows of data in the JSON input are objects with named properties. So You should use **`id: "ID"`** in your case. Moreover you don't need to include in `jsonReader` the properties which value are default (`root:"rows"`, `page: "page"`) and so on.
3. The next problem is the usage of unconditional `reloadGrid` inside of `loadComplete`. You should understand that `loadComplete` will be executed *on every reloading of the grid* (event on local reloading). So it would be wrong making permanent reloading of grid. Moreover usage of `reloadGrid` inside of `loadComplete` is bad from another point of view. If you trigger `reloadGrid` the event will be executed * immediately*, but the grid is not in processing of previous loading. So it would be more correct to trigger reloading inside of `setTimeout` with some small time interval like `50` ms.
4. The last recommendation is usage of [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#K.26R_style) (Kernighan and Ritchie's) style of writing of the code. It's not so important which style of formatting of the code you use in another computer language and it's not important which one you personally find the most nice to read. JavaScript has it's own rights. One from there is *automatic semicolon insertion* (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_syntax#Whitespace_and_semicolons) for example). If you follow K&R you will never have any problems with automatic semicolon insertion.
5. I recommend you to use `height: "auto"` if you need display not so much rows and use column templates which could reduce the size of your code and simplify its management.

After described above changing the could will be something like below

```
var myFloatTemplate = { width: 80, align: "right", sorttype: "float" };

$("#CompTable").jqGrid({
    url: "BomExplosionInJsonObj.asp",
    datatype: "json",
    height: "auto",
    colNames: ["Part", "Description", "Src", "Std Usage", "Usage Inc Scrap", "Rate Scrap", "UOM", "Item", "Unit Cost", "Stock"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "COMP1_PART", width: 120},
        {name: "WSCOMPDESC", width: 300},
        {name: "WSCOMPSRC", width: 40},
        {name: "COMPUSAGE", template: myFloatTemplate},
        {name: "WSGROSSQTY", width: 120, template: myFloatTemplate},
        {name: "COMPRATE_SCRAP", width: 90, template: myFloatTemplate},
        {name: "COMPBASIC_UNIT", width: 60},
        {name: "COMP1_ITEM", width: 60},
        {name: "WSCOMPUNITCOST", template: myFloatTemplate},
        {name: "WSCOMPQTYSTOCK", template: myFloatTemplate}
    ],
    jsonReader: {
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "ID"
    },
    caption: "Bom Detail",
    rowNum: 10000,
    autoencode: true,
    loadonce: true,
    sortable: true,
    sortname: "COMP1_PART",
    //sortorder: "desc",
    loadComplete: function () {
        var $self = $(this);
        if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $self.trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
            }, 50);
        }
    }
});
```

The corresponding demo is [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/Keith.htm). Local sorting works and it displays the following results

[image]

**UPDATED**: Starting with version 4.12.0 [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) fork of jqGrid, which I develop, support new `forceClientSorting: true` option. It works in combination with `loadonce: true` option and allows first load all the data from the server response, then sort the data *locally* and only then to display page of the data. It makes the trick with reloading of grid inside of `setTimeout`, started in `loadComplete`, described in the answer, not needed. One need just replace the above `loadComplete` code to one additional option `forceClientSorting: true`. The option `forceClientSorting: true` have additional two benefits:

1. One don't see any flicker after displaying of the first (unsorted) grid;
2. The performance of the grid is better, especially if it have many rows, because displaying the grid is much slowly as sorting. Moreover the trick with described in the old answer displays the grid, then delete the content (which is slowly too) and then one displays the sorted grid once more.

Comment: That's a great answer - thanks.  The reloadgrid was something I found on another stackoverflow call about client-side sorting.  Just started with jqgrid, so trying to understand how it all works.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted shows that the sorting will be done on the server not on the client. Your jqGrid will post `sord` and `sidx` parameters to allow you to do so as part of returning the data to the jqGrid.

Ex: C# MVC Controller code, where paging is also performed

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters)
{
 ...
 var pagedQuery = wholeDataSet.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows).ToList();
 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Scanned through several answers and tried most of the options, but still the code which was working perfectly on local was not working on deployment.
Finally I removed jquery links of dotnetcdn as well as googleapis and came to basics -

Opened source code on https://jqueryui.com/sortable/
and copied the src  links

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

I am 68 yrs old and three days of struggle was too much.
So sharing the answer on stackoverflow
This is my return gift to all for helping me to learn coding