# Client side sort not working

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid with the following information:

```
$("#Table").jqGrid({
            url: 'u.json,
            loadonce:true,
            colNames: msd.rise.columnDisplayNames,
            colModel: msd.rise.colModelDef,
            gridview: true,
            toppager: false,
            sortname: 'sd',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            sortable:true,
            loadComplete: function(){
                $("#Table").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
            }
});
```

The client side sort doesn't work. I put `loadonce:true` and `$("#Table").setGridParam({datatype:'json', page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');` based of [this](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/client-side-sort-with-dynamic-url) answer. But it still doesn't work. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code of `loadComplete` which you use currently is wrong. You should never use unconditional `.trigger('reloadGrid')` inside of `loadComplete`. Moreover the setting of `datatype` to `'json'` before reloading will makes reloading of data *from the server*, but you need *local* reloading to apply sorting. The correct code will be like in the example from [the anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16383288/315935):

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $self.trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
        }, 50);
    }
}
```

The code makes reloading *only once* after the initial loading from the server will be finished.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I put that inside the code. With settimeout the gird doesn't load correctly (loading is always on top). When I removed setTimeout, it works (loading doesn't appear) but when I click sort, the grid doesn't load again.

Comment: @amandachaw: Probably you have some additional problems in `colModel`. **Could you append your questing with `colModel` which you use and with an example of input data (1-2 rows of data will be enough). Which `datatype` you use?** The line with syntax error `url: 'u.json,` allows me to suppose that you use `datatype: "json"` which you not included in the posted code. If you do use default `datatype: "xml"` then you should change `loadComplete` to test for it: `if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "xml") {`.

Comment: I had rowNum: 0, I removed that and your code now working:) Thank you very much for the help. yes, the datatype is json.