# JqGrid Search Tollbar not working properly

Tags: jqgrid

I have a problem my grid

The problem is my grid is not a loadonce so the toggle search is not working well,but when I change the loadonce:true,it works perfectly.

NOw my question is,how can I stop the toogle search not to request on server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are only two possibility: either jqGrid hold local data and it can do sorting, paging and filtering (searching) locally or the server have to do this. jqGrid hold the data locally in internal options `data` and `_index` only if the `datatype` is not `'json'` and not `'xml'` or if the option `loadonce: true` are used.

So if you use `datatype: 'json'` or `datatype: 'xml'` and you still need to have *local searching* you *have to* use `loadone: true`. In the case the internal options `data` and `_index` will be filled and the `datatype` will be changed to `'local'` after the first loading of data from the server. If you will need later to reload the data from the server you can reset the `datatype` to its original value ('json' or 'xml') with respect of `setGridParam` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3772720/315935) for example) and trigger "reloadGrid" event (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)).