# jqGrid and search filter. Best way to repopulate data

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I've been playing with jqGrid for quite a long time now but never gone deeper into details about performance.
I don't use the built-in jqGrid search form cause I prefer to have my own toolbar where the user inputs some data he/she wants to filter.

I've always wrapped my grid in a function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var myGrid = jQuery("#MyGrid");

    $("#cmdSearch").bind('click', function (e) {
        myGrid.GridUnload();
        LoadMyGrid($("#Filter1").val(), $("#Filter2").val())
    });

    function LoadMyGrid(param1, param2) {
        myGrid.jqGrid({
            url: 'myUrl',
            postData: { Param1: param1, Param2: param2 },
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['Column1', 'Column2'],
            colModel: [
                       { name: 'colum1', index: 'colum1', sortable: true, width: 100 },
                       { name: 'colum2', index: 'colum2', sortable: true, width: 100 }
                      ],
            pager: $('#MyPager'),
            rowList: [10, 50, 100],
            rowNum: 10,
            viewrecords: false,
            shrinkToFit: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            hidegrid: false,
            emptyrecords: "No records."
        });
    }
});
```

and unloaded it (`GridUnload`) before recreating it. I was wondering if this is the best way to do it or there might be some performance/memory issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of `GridUnload()` in the example is not the best way. I would rewrite you code as following

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var myGrid = jQuery("#MyGrid");

    myGrid.jqGrid({
        url: 'myUrl',
        postData: {
            Param1: function() { return $("#Filter1").val(); },
            Param2: function() { return $("#Filter2").val(); }
        },
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['Column1', 'Column2'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'colum1', index: 'colum1', sortable: true, width: 100 },
            { name: 'colum2', index: 'colum2', sortable: true, width: 100 }
        ],
        pager: '#MyPager',
        rowList: [10, 50, 100],
        rowNum: 10,
        viewrecords: false,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rownumbers: true,
        hidegrid: false,
        emptyrecords: "No records."
    });

    $("#cmdSearch").click(function() {
        myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid',[{page:1}]);
    });
});
```

In the code I use the idea of usage functions as the property of `postData` which I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2928371/how-to-filter-the-jqgrid-data-not-using-the-built-in-search-filter-box/2928819#2928819). One can reduce the 'click' handle to the `myGrid.trigger('reloadGrid');`. In the case at all grid reloading (for example at the sorting or paging) will be used the current values from the `$("#Filter1")` and `$("#Filter2")` controls. The grid itself will be not destroyed and recreated. instead of that only the grid data will be reloaded. About different additional parameters of `reloadGrid` see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014).

Small change from `pager: $('#MyPager')` to `pager: '#MyPager'` I want a little comment. If you look at [the jqGrid source code](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/grid.base.js#L2164) you will find

```
if(typeof ts.p.pager == "string") {if(ts.p.pager.substr(0,1) !="#") {
    ts.p.pager = "#"+ts.p.pager;}
} else { ts.p.pager = "#"+ $(ts.p.pager).attr("id");}
```

So if you use `pager` parameter in the form `$('#MyPager')` if will be "normalized" to '#MyPager'. After I read this I use only `pager: '#MyPager'` syntax.

Comment: Wonderful solution. Thanks Oleg. Always the best.