# Reload Jqgrid by given interval

Tags: jqgrid

I want to reload a jqgrid each 5 min (given interval time), is there any option/event.
how to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` JavaScript function to do automatic refreshing

```
var grid = $("#list"),
    intervalId = setInterval(
        function() {
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
        },
        300000); // 300 sec === 5 min
```

to stop the grid reload you can use one more JavaScript function:

```
clearInterval(intervalId);
```

In the "reloadGrid" I use less known parameter `current:true` which is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014) to  preserve the current selection in the grid.

Comment: Awesome! Another helpful jQGrid answer by Oleg!

Comment: @FastTrack: You are welcome! [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10461964/315935) could be interesting for you in connection with automatic reloading of grids