# jqGrid reload doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, jqgrid

I am having a problem with reloading the grid with trigger('reloadGrid').
I send an AJAX call to the server and the server returns the xmlstring just fine. but the grid does not load the new data. 
heres my code:

```
$('#tasks').jqGrid({
        datatype: "xmlstring",
        datastr: <?php echo json_encode($_xml); ?>,
        colNames: ["Date","TaskID","Subject","Notes","Due Date"],
        colModel: [ 
            {name: "Date", index:"AssignDate",align: "center", xmlmap:"AssignDate"},
            {name: "TaskID", index:"TaskID",xmlmap:"TaskID", align:"center"},
            {name: "Subject", index:"TaskSubject", align: "center", xmlmap:"TaskSubject"},
            {name:"Notes", index:"Notes", align: "center",height: 20,xmlmap:"Notes"},
            {name:"Due Date", index:"DueDate", align: "center",height: 20,xmlmap:"DueDate"}
        ],
        height: 250,
        viewRecords: true,
        autowidth: true,
        xmlReader: {
            root: "tasks",
            row: "task",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#navTasks'),
        caption: "Your Tasks"});
setInterval(
    function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'register.php',
        data: {uID:uID},
        dataType: 'xmlstring',
        success: function(xml)
        {
            $("#tasks").setGridParam({datastr: xml, datatype: "xmlstring"}).trigger('reloadGrid')
        }
    });},10000);
```

here is my register.php file:

```
$uID = $_GET['uID'];
$host="127.0.0.1:3306";
$db_name='wf_db';
$tbl_name="tasks";
$connect = new mysqli("$host","root"," ","$db_name")or die('Can\'t connect to database!');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE UserID='$uID' and Task_Completed='0'";
$query_data = mysqli_query($connect,$sql)or die('Couldnt get data');
$row = mysqli_num_rows($query_data);
if($row != 0){ 
    $_xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>\r\n";
    $_xml .="<tasks>\r\n";
    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($query_data)) {
         if ($result["TaskID"]) {
            $_xml .="\t<task>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<TaskID>" . $result["TaskID"] . "</TaskID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<UserID>" . $result["UserID"] . "</UserID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<AssignID>" . $result["AssignID"] . "</AssignID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<AssignDate>" . $result["Assign_Date"] . "</AssignDate>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<DueDate>" . $result["Due_Date"] . "</DueDate>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<AssignUser>" . $result["Assign_User"] . "</AssignUser>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<TaskSubject>" . $result["Task_Subject"] . "</TaskSubject>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<Notes>" . $result["Notes"] . "</Notes>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<TrackID>" . $result["TrackID"] . "</TrackID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<Details>" . $result["Completion_Details"] . "</Details>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t</task>\r\n";
         } else {
            $_xml .="\t<task>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<TaskID></TaskID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<UserID></UserID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<AssignID></AssignID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<AssignDate></AssignDate>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<DueDate></DueDate>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<AssignUser></AssignUser>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<TaskSubject></TaskSubject>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<Notes></Notes>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<TrackID></TrackID>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t\t<Details></Details>\r\n";
            $_xml .="\t</task>\r\n";
         }
    }

 $_xml .="</tasks>";

echo json_encode($_xml);

 } 
 else {
    echo 'Oops something went wrong!';
}
```

UPDATE:

```
    var data = <?php echo json_encode($_xml); ?>;
    var uID = <?php echo $uID; ?>;$grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "xmlstring",
        datastr: data, url: 'register.php',
        sortname: 'Job ID',
        sortOrder: 'asc',
        postData: {uID:uID},
        colNames: ["track","Job ID","Subject","Notes","Details","Due Date"],
        colModel: [ 
            {name: "track",  index:"TrackID",align: "center", xmlmap:"TrackID", hidden: true, sortable: true},
            {name: "Job ID", index:"TaskID",xmlmap:"TaskID", align:"center",sortable: true, sorttype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: false, editoptions: {readonly: true}},
            {name: "Subject", index:"TaskSubject", align: "center", xmlmap:"TaskSubject",sorttype: 'text', sortable: true,editable: false, editoptions: {readonly: true}},
            {name:"Notes", index:"Notes", align: "center",height: 20,xmlmap:"Notes",sorttype: 'text', sortable: true,editable: false, editoptions: {readonly: true}},
            {name:"Details", index:"Details", align: "center", xmlmap:"Details", editable: true, edittype: 'select', editoptions: {value: 'Not Started:Not Started;In Progress:In Progress;Completed:Completed'}, sortable: true},
            {name:"Due Date", index:"DueDate", align: "center", xmlmap:"DueDate",sorttype: 'text', sortable: true, editable: true, editoptions: {dataInit: initDateEdit}, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: {newformat: 'd-M-Y'}, datefmt: 'd-M-Y'}
        ],


        editurl: 'editRow.php',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10,20,50],
        viewRecords: true,
        xmlReader: {
            root: "tasks",
            row: "task",
            repeatitems: false
        },
        pager: $('#navTasks'),
        caption: "Your Tasks"
    }).navGrid('#navTasks',{<?php
        if ($user==NULL){
            echo 'edit:false,add:false,del:false';
        }
        else{
            echo 'edit:false,add:false,del:false';
        }
    ?>},{},{},{},{multipleSearch: false, multipleGroup: false});


    setInterval(
    function(){
    $grid.trigger('reloadGrid',[{current:true}]);},6000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you uses [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) which don't know the `dataType: 'xmlstring'`. You means `dataType: 'xml'`.

Second You misunderstood the `datatype: 'xmlstring'`. Instead of the usage of separate `$.ajax` call you can use

```
datatype: 'xml',
url: 'register.php',
postData: {uID: uID},
```

options of jqGrid. You can consider to implement `uID` property of the `postData` as method (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) for details). The body of `setInterval` can be reduced to the call of `$("#tasks").trigger('reloadGrid', [{current: true}]);` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5297156/315935) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)).

If you need don't load the grid body at the first and do loading only inside of `setInterval` you can set `datatype: 'local'` and change `datatype` to `'xml'` with respect of `setGridParam` like you do already.

Moreover I don't use PHP myself, but nevertheless I would recommend you to use `DOMDocument` from [PHP DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) (see for example [here](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/dom.html) or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-xmldomphp/) for details) instead of writing the XML manually. Direct construction of XML text can produce many errors. For example you can't place characters like `<` directly as the content of XML elements without its encoding. At least [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) sections should be used.

Comment: wow ok thanks a lot for all the info but after following most of that(except php to XML) ...I am still stuck with the original problem, the grid does not refresh every x seconds with the new records. I will post the code if you need it.

Comment: @user1160022: You are welcome! To be able to help you to localize the problem I need of course the current code which you use. Moreover if could be important to know where you defines (or assign) the `uID`. If would be good if you post the XML response which will be produced by the server.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didnt have internet connection for a few days. I have updated my original question, have look and let me know where I am going wrong. Thanks!
I have also added some more functionality to the grid.

Comment: @user1160022: I can't test the PHP code which you posted. Could you post just the XML response without the code which produce it. You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to catch the HTTP traffic and to see exact response body.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<tasks>
 <task>
  <TaskID>IF2764</TaskID>
  <DueDate></DueDate>
  <TaskSubject>Testing1</TaskSubject>
  <Notes>Oops</Notes>
  <TrackID>1</TrackID>
  <Details>In Progress</Details>
 </task>
 <task>
  <TaskID>TD1234</TaskID>
  <DueDate></DueDate>
  <TaskSubject>Test</TaskSubject>
  <Notes>testing databases and tables, hopefully this works</Notes>
  <TrackID>4</TrackID>
  <Details>Not Started</Details>
 </task>
</tasks>

Comment: It looks like the grid refreshes but the grid doesnt make a call to register.php. I checked firebug for any calls to the server...i know it refreshes since any changes that arent saved are reverted back to the original

Comment: @user1160022: Try [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/user1160022.htm). If you use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) you will see that every 6 sec the request like `/jqGrid/user1160022.xml?uID=any+data&_search=false&nd=1328183664491&rows=10&page=1&sidx=Job+ID&sord=asc` will be sent and the data received from the server. The grid will be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks Oleg I figured it out! The problem was that I needed to set the postData parameter for the reload. Works great now! Thanks a lot.