# Jqgrid in jquery ui tabs

Tags: button, jqgrid, toolbar, addition

I have a custom button for my jqgrid that when pressed takes me to another view.
But for some reason when i navigate between the tabs there is an extra added custom button every time a re-visit that tab. Is there a way to say only to add this button once?

This is the markup:

```
$('#tabs').tabs( {
    show: function (event, ui) {
        if(ui.index == 0) {
           Show some content on this tab.. Not important.
        }

        if(ui.index == 1) {
            $("#functionslist").jqGrid({
                datatype: 'json',
                url: '/Admin/GetFunctionsList',
                colNames: ['Namn'],
                colModel: [
                           { index: 'FunctionName', 
                             name: 'FunctionName', 
                             width: 100, 
                             sortable: false 
                           }
                          ],
                 rowNum: 20,
                 prmNames: { sort: 'SortColumn', order: 'SortOrder', page: 'Page', rows: 'Rows', search: null, nd: null },
                 hidegrid: false,
                 pager: '#functionspager',
                 autowidth: true,
                 shrinkToFit: true,
                 height: '100%',
                 caption: 'Functions',
                 viewrecords: true,
                 onSelectRow: function (id) {
                        window.location.href = '/Function/Edit/' + id;
                 }
             }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#functionspager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false })
             .navButtonAdd('#functionspager', {
                 caption: '',
                 title: 'Create new function',
                 buttonicon: 'ui-icon-plus',
                 onClickButton: function () {
                     window.location = '/Function/Add/';
                 }
             }); .... and so forth....
```

Everything runs fine and i have the behavior i desire but for some reason when i navigate between the two tabs more and more custom button are added. Any ideas why, have tried to resolve this but with no luck.

/Daniel

Answer (score 0):

Why not check to see if the button already exists before adding it?

```
 if ($('#functionspager :has(".ui-icon-plus")').length == 0) {
     $("#functionslist").jqGrid('navGrid', '#functionspager', { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false })
         .navButtonAdd('#functionspager', {
            ...
          });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The call `$("#functionslist").jqGrid({/*parameters*/);` convert the empty `<table>` to a grid having columns, capture, pager and so on. You should make the call **once** and not repeat it on every tab activation.

Exactly in the same way the methods `navGrid` and `navButtonAdd` should be called **only once**.

So you should decide what should be done if the user select the tab having jqGrid. You can for example call

```
$("#functionslist").trigger('reloadGrid', [{current:true}]);
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3807623/jqgrid-paging-question/3808014#3808014) for details)