# Selecting row after updating record using jqgrid

Tags: c#, javascript, jqgrid

I'm having a problem with regards to JQgrid.

here is my code for my grid.
i'm using clientsideevents of "beforerowselect" and "loadcomplete" 
note: i'm using load complete for the reload of the grid 
everytime the grid reloads it will select the item.

```
<trirand:JQGrid ID="jqgrid" runat="server" Height="475px" Width="1510px" MultiSelect="false" ShrinkToFit="true" AutoWidth="true">
<ClientSideEvents BeforeRowSelect="beforeSelect" LoadComplete="loadComplete"/>
```

In "beforeselectevent" what i do here is to get the cellvalue of 
the rowid of "itemid".

I tried to create a session variable to store the value of the "ItemID"
and store it in the var sessionItemID for me to be able to pass it on "load complete event". 

Problem: but everytime i tried to insert breakpoint here it always gives me '' value.

```
function beforeSelect(rowid, e) {
                grid = $("#<%= jqgrid.ClientID %>");
                ItemID = grid.jqGrid('getCell', rowid, 'ItemID');
                var sessionItemID = '<%=Session["ItemID"] %>';
}
```

here in "loadcomplete" event. I passed the sessionItemID so that i can get the ItemID.
so everytime i update the item on the grid. 
it will reload the page and select the item that i updated. 

Problem: after it reloads, it doesn't select the item after it reloads.

```
function loadComplete(sessionItemID ) {
                if (ItemID != 0 || ItemID != null) {
                    grid = $("#<%= jqgrid.ClientID %>");
                    grid.trigger("reloadgrid");
                    grid.jqgrid('setselection', "2" );
                }
            }
```

what i want to achieve is this (to make the story short) 
 1. select row on the grid, form will pop-up then update record. 
 2. after updating record the user will save the page then close. 
 3. grid will reload 
 4. it will remember the selected/updated item.

I'm really confused on what will i do next. Thanks

Comment: Try storing  rowid in a hidden field

Comment: i tried to store it in hidden field but when i passed the value, still gave me undefined value.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have some spelling mistakes in your method names,

change `grid.jqgrid('setselection', "2" );` to `grid.jqGrid('setSelection', "2" );`

2 changes `jqgrid` to `jqGrid` and `setselection` to `setSelection`

UPDATE : if it is to retain the selection after update you can achieve this by `current:true` in reloadgrid

Remove the code in loadComplete and add it to aftersaveFunc like given below

```
                    grid = $("#<%= jqgrid.ClientID %>");
                    grid.trigger("reloadGrid",[{current:true}]);
```

Please note the `reloadGrid` is camel case (G is upper)

Comment: even if i change it to that format. it still wont work after all. =)

Comment: is aftersavecell and aftersavefunction the same?
i've added it in clientsideevents

Answer (score 0):

To solve the described problem you can try to use [reloadAfterSubmit: false](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing#properties) option of form editing to *prevent* reloading of the grid st the end of row editing. If you don't add new rows the option could be the best way.

Alternatively you can use `afterSubmit` callback or `jqGridAddEditAfterSubmit` event to save current selection and restore it after the text loading of the grid. The corresponding code could be about the following:

```js
$("#jqgrid").bind("jqGridAddEditAfterSubmit", function () {
    this.grid.selectionPreserver(this);
});
```

Comment: hi @oleg, I tried to use this code on my program and it works.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881717/how-to-highlight-the-last-selected-row-after-client-side-sorting-on-jqgrid

Comment: but I want to add some feature which is the positioning the scroll bar, For example. I have 500 row, if I click on 250th suppose the position of the scroll bar is on the middle. I want it also to set the position where the selected item is. Can you help me with this?

Comment: hi @Oleg can you help me with this?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142993/getting-the-sum-using-footerdata