# getting the sum using footerdata on jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid, footer

I have a column name Total. 
And I'm also using the footer 
value of the jqgrid.

Example this is the column

Total 
100 
-98
-76
98
76

how can I get the sum of the row 
using the footer data.

here is my code. 
note: if i use 'sum' it gives me 'NaN' 
value.

```
var parseTotal= grid.jqGrid('getCol', 'Total', false, 'sum');
grid.jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Total: parseTotal});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should post more full code which reproduce the problem. I tried some options: the input data as string, the data as integers, using `formatter: "integer"`, using no formatters and so on.

I found no input data of no column definition which produce the described results. Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum1.htm)

[image]

which works and compare with your non working demo. I hope you will find the error in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you put the above code in gridComplete function like this:

```
 gridComplete: function(){
            var parseTotal=  $(this).jqGrid('getCol', 'Total', false, 'sum');
             $(this).jqGrid('footerData', 'set', { Total: parseTotal});
          }
```

Now, the issue of returning NaN occurs when one of the cells in the column contain a null value(white space). So , to convert white spaces to value 0, use `number` formatter in the colmodel for column `total`:

ie;

```
colModel:[
  ...............
    {name:"Total",index:"Total", formatter: 'number'},
   ......
],
```

Also ensure that the column index is correctly spelled.

Answer (score 0):

Not a jqGrid expert by any means, but shouldn't the column referenced in the 'getCol' method be the column you want to sum -- 'amount' -- instead of the column into which you want to put the sum -- 'Total'?  The Nan comes from trying to sum a column that is as yet undefined.