# How to put data on the total "FooterRow"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using **jqGrid** plugin *4.6.0* with **jQuery** *1.11.0* to generate a report that needs the total in the summary. I was only able to generate the total grouped by column. jqGrid has a property called *footerrow* that is supposed to be the summary of the grid.

I need to place the total of the whole report in the FooterRow, but I was not able to do it.

```
$("#respostaRelatorio").jqGrid({
    url: urlRelatorio + "?" + dadosRelatorio,
    colModel: modeloColunas,
    mtype: "POST",
    altRows: true,
    datatype: "json",
    loadonce: true,
    height: "auto",
    width: 1130,
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList: [ 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 ],
    viewrecords: true,
    pager: "#paginacao",
    sortorder: "asc",
    shrinkToFit: false,
    headertitles: true,
    loadui: "disable",
    rownumbers: true,
    autoencode: true,
    caption: "Resultados encontrados",
    deselectAfterSort: true,
    gridview: true,
    idPrefix: "id",
    rowTotal: 4000,
    sortable: true,
    toppager: true,
    resizable: true,
    grouping: true,
    groupingView: {
        groupField: [ 'loginMedico' ],
        groupCollapse: false,
        groupOrder: [ 'asc' ],
        groupSummary: [ true ],
        groupDataSorted: true
    },
    footerrow: true,
    userDataOnFooter: true
});

var modeloColunas = [
    { name: "loginMedico", index: "loginMedico", jsonmap: "loginMedico", label: "Login M&eacute;dico", sortable: true, sorttype: "text", summaryType: "count", summaryTpl: "total" },
    { name: "nomeMedico", index: "nomeMedico", jsonmap: "nomeMedico", label: "Nome do M&eacute;dico", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" },
    { name: "perfilMedico", index: "perfilMedico", jsonmap: "perfilMedico", label: "Perfil M&eacute;dico", sortable: true, sorttype: "text"},
    { name: "tipoSolicitacao", index: "tipoSolicitacao", jsonmap: "tipoSolicitacao", label: "Tipo da Solicita&ccedil;&atilde;o", sortable: true, sorttype: "text" },
    { name: "cancelada", index: "cancelada", jsonmap: "cancelada", label: "Cancelada", sortable: true, sorttype: "int" },
    { name: "liberada", index: "liberada", jsonmap: "liberada", label: "Liberada", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryType: "sum" },
    { name: "negada", index: "negada", jsonmap: "negada", label: "Negada", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryType: "sum" },
    { name: "pendente", index: "pendente", jsonmap: "pendente", label: "Pendente", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryType: "sum" },
    { name: "total", index: "total", jsonmap: "total", label: "Total", sortable: true, sorttype: "int", summaryTpl: "total"} ];
```

Comment: Simple to do but can you please provide the generated HTML of the grid? include the footerrow if you can and some sample data. :) thanks!

Comment: there is no html, is the plugin that generates the grid.

Answer (score 3):

Crossposting (and translating) my [answer on SO-PT (written in Portuguese)](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/9433/100):

---

Check out [this example](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithTotalSum1.htm).

Basically, you need to add an `loadComplete` function to your `jqGrid`, it will be used to build the `footerData`:

```
loadComplete: function () {
    var $self = $(this);
    var sumCanceled = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "cancelada", false, "sum");
    var sumReleased = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "liberada", false, "sum");
    var sumDenied = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "negada", false, "sum");
    var sumPending = $self.jqGrid("getCol", "pendente", false, "sum");

    $self.jqGrid("footerData", "set", {
        loginMedico: "Total:", 
        cancelada: sumCanceled, 
        liberada: sumReleased,  
        negada: sumDenied,
        pendente: sumPending
    });
}
```

---

Source: [getting the sum using footerdata on jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16142993/getting-the-sum-using-footerdata-on-jqgrid)