# free jQgrid 4.9.2, On delete confirmation box showing Id of dropdown instead text value

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, free-jqgrid

**NOTE:** As per Oleg suggestion I have implemented a formatter: 'select' property to dropdown to get selected Id in `custom func`

I upgraded my jQgrid from version 4.8.2 to 4.9.2. Due to this I am facing problem while deleting any record of drop-down column.

While deleting a record, I display a message box to take confirmation from user. In that message box I want show the selected text value of dropdown which I want delete. But instead of showing text value its showing me the selected value (GUID) like this : [image]

But I want to show selected text of that dropdown. To get more clarity as per coding perspective I am pasting my jQgrid code

```
function RenderPOFieldsGrid() {
if (g_bEditMode) {
    var oGrid = $('#tbPOFields'), topPagerSelector = '#' + $.jgrid.jqID(oGrid[0].id) + "_toppager", lastSel;

    oGrid.jqGrid({
        url: sRelativePath + '/WSAjax.asmx/GetDataForGridInEdit',
        mtype: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8" },
        serializeGridData: function (data) {
            return JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        jsonReader: {
            root: "d.rows",
            page: "d.page",
            total: "d.total",
            records: "d.records"
        },
        colNames: ['ConsigneeId', 'Consignee'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'ConsigneeId', index: 'ConsigneeId', hidden: true },
            { name: 'Consignee', index: 'Consignee', sortable: false, title: false, width: 42, editable: true, edittype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
                editrules: {
                    required: true,
                    custom: true,
                    custom_func: function (value, colName) {
                        if ($('#tbItems_Consignee').length === 1) {
                            var selrow = $('#tbItems').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                            $('#tbItems').jqGrid('setCell', selrow, 'ConsigneeId', value);
                        }

                        if (g_bEditMode && value === g_sValueNONE && !g_bIsOrderType_Maintenance)
                            return [false, " is an invalid Consignee.<br/>Please select a valid Consignee before saving."];
                        else {
                            return [true, ""];
                        }
                    }
                },
                editoptions:
                {
                    value: eval('(' + g_oConsigneeList + ')'),
                    dataEvents: [
                        { type: 'keyup', fn: function (e) { $(e.target).trigger('change'); } },
                        {
                            type: 'change',
                            fn: function (e) {
                                if (!e.isTrigger) {
                                    var selrow = $('#tbItems').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                                    var ConsigneeId = $(this).val();
                                    $('#tbItems').jqGrid('setCell', selrow, 'ConsigneeId', ConsigneeId);
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                }
            }
        ],
        prmNames: { page: "pageIndex", rows: "pageSize", sort: "sortIndex", order: "sortDirection" },
        autowidth: true,
        postData: {
            filters: null,
            spName: 'GetPOFieldsDetailsList',
            paramXML: ''
        },
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        rowNum: 1000,
        rowList: [1000],
        sortname: "",
        sortorder: "asc",
        page: 1,
        gridview: true,
        toppager: true,
        autoencode: true,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Fields',
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        emptyrecords: "No records to view.",
        footerrow: true,
        onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
            if (rowid && rowid != lastSel) {
                if (typeof lastSel !== "undefined") {
                    $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSel);
                }
                lastSel = rowid;
            }
        }
    });
    oGrid.jqGrid('navGrid', topPagerSelector, { add: false, edit: false, search: false, refresh: false }, {}, {}, myDelParams, {});
    oGrid.jqGrid('inlineNav', topPagerSelector, {
        addParams: myFieldAddParams
        editParams: myFieldsEditParams
    });    
  }
}


var myDelParams = {
    processing: true,
   // because I use "local" data I don't want to send the changes
   // to the server so I use "processing:true" setting and delete
   // the row manually in onclickSubmit
   onclickSubmit: function (options, rowid) {
      var gridId = $.jgrid.jqID($(this)[0].id);
      // reset the value of processing option which could be modified
      options.processing = true;

      DeleteExpenseDetails(rowid);

      $.jgrid.hideModal("#delmod" + gridId,
                          { gb: "#gbox_" + gridId,
                              jqm: options.jqModal, onClose: options.onClose
                          });

      return true;
  },
  beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var rowId = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Do you really want delete the <b>   Consignee: " + $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Consignee') + "</b>?");
  },
  afterShowForm: function ($form) {
    var dialog = $form.closest('div.ui-jqdialog'),
        selRowId = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'),
        selRowCoordinates = $('#' + selRowId).offset();

    dialog.offset(selRowCoordinates);
    dialog.css('width', 'auto');
  }
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to reproduce your problem because there are no working demo with test data.

I suppose that you used before the code without `formatter: 'select'` and now you added the property to the column `Consignee`. Additionally you changed the data used as input for jqGrid from textes to values (ids). Thus you get now `$(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Consignee')` the value instead of the text in the Delete dialog. Migration from free jqGrid 4.8.2 to 4.9.2 seems to me independent from the problem.

The solution of the problem seems to me in changing the code of `beforeShowForm` which you use in Delete form. After getting the value from the column `Consignee` (by using `$(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Consignee')`) you have to convert the value to the text using `editoptions.value` property of the column. You use currently just `value: eval('(' + g_oConsigneeList + ')')` in your code. So it's unclear for me which format of data you use for `value`. In any way the usage of `value: $.parseJSON('(' + g_oConsigneeList + ')')` seems me better to have less security problems. To convert the value to the text you need to parse `editoptions.value` property. jqGrid allows you different forms of the `value`. If you use object form for example then you can use the following code

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        val = $self.jqGrid("getCell", p.selrow, "Consignee"),
        cm = p.colModel[p.iColByName.Consignee],
        editVal = cm.editoptions.value;
    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Do you really want delete the <b>   Consignee: " +
        editVal[val] + "</b>?");
}
```

If you use string form of `editoptions.value` property then you should replace the value `editVal[val]` to a little more complex code. You will need to split `editoptions.value` by `;` first and to split every resulting element by `:` to have value to text mapping. Then you will need find the text which corresponds the value.

**UPDATED**: One more way to get the data from the cell in exactly the form which jqGrid display there is the following:

```
beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
    var $self = $(this), p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam"),
        tr = $self.jqGrid("getGridRowById", p.selrow),
        $cell = $.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell.call(this, tr, p.iColByName.Consignee);

    $("td.delmsg", $form[0]).html("Do you really want delete the <b>   Consignee: " +
        $cell.text() + "</b>?");
}
```

The helper method `$.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell` get us the `<td>` element or an inner part of the cell if some wrapper are used. One cal then use `$cell.text()` to get the required data.

Comment: The value comes in variable `g_oConsigneeList` in the form of JSON

Comment: @Rahul: Sorry, but the information "the form of JSON" get practically no information. The string `'{"val1":"text1","val2":"text2"}'` is correct JSON string and `$.parseJSON('{"val1":"text1","val2":"text2"}')` is **object** `{val1: "text1", val2: "text2"}`. In the same way `'\"val1:text1;val2:text2\"'` is correct JSON string too and `$.parseJSON('\"val1:text1;val2:text2\"')` return **string** `"val1:text1;val2:text2"`. Nevertheless `value: {val1: "text1", val2: "text2"}` should be parsed and be used in another way as `value: "val1:text1;val2:text2"`.

Comment: Thank you Oleg sir. Its absolutely working fine. But just as a curiosity I am asking that this is the only solution or it is work around for only my problem?

Comment: Because in previous versions we just need to do `getCell` to access the value and I was expected such type of solution. Please do not feel bad for this doubt.

Comment: @Rahul: You filled the grid with the text instead of values before you used `formatter: 'select'`. Now you fill the column with values and `setCell`, `getCell` work with the values too. By the way I see one more way to get the text from the cell. You can use `$.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell.call(this, $grid.jqGrid("getGridRowById", rowid), p.iColByName.Consignee).text()`. The helper method `$.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell` can be used to get the data from the grid in the form like it be (displayed) in the grid. (`var rowid = p.selrow`)

Comment: @Rahul: see **UPDATED** part of the answer.

Comment: I appreciate that as per request, you provide me another solution. I tried to implement second solution you provided. Its giving me an error on line of code `$cell = $.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell.call(this, tr, p.iColByName.Consignee);` and error is `Cannot read property 'treeGrid' of undefined`

Comment: @Rahul: You should provide more full code which you use. I suppose that you used the line `$cell = $.jgrid.getDataFieldOfCell.call(this, tr, p.iColByName.Consignee)` in wrong context. The exact code from **UPDATED** part of my answer have `this` initialized to the DOM of the grid (`$('#tbPOFields')[0]`), but the error "Cannot read property 'treeGrid' of undefined" means that `this` have wrong value in your case.