# Retain the previous checked state of checkboxes after Reload of JqGrid having Multiselect = true

Tags: jqgrid

I am developing an application using MVC and I am using JqGrid to display the data.

The JqGrid is inside Views\Shared folder as partial page.

This grid is loaded as partial page in another View (Home.cshtml).

Multiselect option of the grid is set to True so that the first column is shown as Checkbox for all rows.

This Grid is loaded/refreshed in intervals of 2 minutes using Javascript SetInterval.

When I select the checkboxes of the Grid row, the checked state of checkbox is not retained after Grid is refreshed in the intervals of 2 minutes.

Kindly help me with the solution to this problem, the previous checked state of checkbox should be retained after Grid refresh. Thanks.

Comment: Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @TonyTomov: I am using version 4.4.4 of jqGrid.

Comment: There is a such option which do exactly this, but it is available in Guriddo jqGrid (commercial product) from version 5.3.2. See [here](http://www.guriddo.net/documentation/guriddo/javascript/about/release-notes/#additions-and-updates_5)

Comment: Have you seen the examples here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6881717/how-to-highlight-the-last-selected-row-after-client-side-sorting-on-jqgrid