# JQGrid paginator's textbox is not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, keypress

My JQGrid's Paginator not working as expected. Navigation buttons are working fine. But when enter the page number manually and pressed enter key, it is not working. I have tried all the possible options. But still it is not working. Can somebody help me to identify the issue.

Here is my grid creation code:

```
$("#ptSPSDataGrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        data: localdata,
        colModel: colmod,
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 25, 50],
        pager: '#ptSPSPager',
        page: 1,
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        viewrecords: true,  
        altRows:  true,        
        loadtext: "Loading parts data...", 
        caption: 'Part Data',
        width: 713,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        scrollOffset: 0,
        height: '100%',
        loadComplete: function() {
            $("#ptSPSDataGrid").trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
        } 
    }); 
$("#ptSPSDataGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', '#ptSPSPager', { add: false, edit: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: false });
            $("#ptSPSDataGrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#ptSPSPager', {
                caption: "Show/Hide Columns",
                title: "Click here to select the columns to view",
                onClickButton: function () { //Adding some code
                 },
        position: "last"
    });
```

Comment: what the type data is you use, JSON or XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the lines

```
loadComplete: function() {
    $("#ptSPSDataGrid").trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
}
```

The event `reloadGrid` reset the `page` parameter to `1` if you not explicitly set additional parameter (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)).

What you probably want to do is to trigger reload **only once**. So you can change the code to something like

```
var firstLoad = true;

$("#ptSPSDataGrid").jqGrid({
    datatype: 'local',
    data: localdata,
    ... // other parameters
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (firstLoad) {
            $(this).trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
            firstLoad = false;
        }
    } 
});
```