# jqgrid paging issue - Not loaded data with page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I am using Jqgrid with customized Edit, Delete buttons. Also , I am using external search to search in grid. I am fustrating with one problem since two days.

Please check my code below of binding jqgrid

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var myGrid = $('#list');

    myGrid.jqGrid({
        url: '/Site/GetData/',
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
        mtype: 'POST',
        loadonce: true,
        colNames: ['Site ID', 'Site Name', 'Email Address', 'Website', 'Contact Person', 'Phone number', 'Mobile number', "Edit", "Delete"],
        colModel:
        [
            { name: 'SiteID', hidden: true },
            { name: 'SiteName' },
            { name: 'EmailID' },
            { name: 'Website' },
            { name: 'ContactPerson' },
            { name: 'PhoneNo' },
            { name: 'MobileNo' },
            { name: 'Edit', width: 50, sortable: false, formatter: ColumnFormatter },
            { name: 'Delete', width: 60, sortable: false, formatter: ColumnFormatter },
        ],
        autowidth: true,
        rowNum: 5,
        rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        sortorder: "desc",
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        ignoreCase: true,

    }).navGrid('#pager',
        {
            rowNum: 5, edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: false, refresh: true
        }
       );
});
```

Using Above code I am binding Jqgrid.
Now, I need to delete a row from the grid, after deleting I need to refresh whole the grid. But it does not kept data according to page. Please check my delete function below :

```
 function deleteRow(imageElement, UserId) {
    var data = new Object();
    data.id = UserId;
    var _data = JSON.stringify(data);
    $("#list").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' });
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Site")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: _data,
        success: function (result) {
            var currentPage = $('#gridData').getGridParam('page');
            $('#list').trigger('reloadGrid');
            $("#list").setGridParam({ page: currentPage })
        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert("This data can not be deleted");
        }
    });
}
```

Okay , using above code , I am deleting row, and if response is Success than need to reload whole the grid.

Now if I am at 2nd page and deleting any row, than it will reloads the grid , it shows me Page number is set as 2. But records shows me from 1st page of grid.

Please help me for that

Answer (score 0):

I' m not sure that I correctly understand the behavior which you need to implement. If you want to reload the whole grid **from the server** then you should reset the value of `datatype` before reloading. The reason: you use `loadonce: true` which loads the data from the server *once*, save it in internal jqGrid parameters `data` and `_index` and then the `datatype` will be changed to `"local"`. So if you want to reload the data from the server you should execute

```js
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam', {datatype: 'json'});
```

*before* `reloadGrid`.

Additionally if you need to reload grid with *specific* page you can use `page` parameter of jqGrid (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935) for details). In the most cases the usage of `current:true` option is what one need. So the code should be something like below

```js
...
success: function (result) {
    $("#list").setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' })
        .trigger('reloadGrid', [{ current: true }]);
}
```