# jQGrid setGridParam function is not working with MVC Action

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I try to filter **jQgrid** data with a date field. Please see my below image.

[image]

There is a two text boxes and a button in my webpage. I try to filter the customer data

in between the selected date range. I call my setGridParam inside the button click event.

Please see my HTML below.

```
 $("#Button1").click(function () {

    var fromdate = $("#txtFrom").val();
    var todate = $("#txtTo").val();

    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('setGridParam', {
        url: "/Home/GetFilterData?sidx=" + fromdate + "&sord=" + todate, page: 1
    }).trigger("reloadGrid");

});
```

And this is my controller action

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetFilterData(string sidx, string sord)
    {
        using (jQGridDemoEntities db = new jQGridDemoEntities())
        {
            var customers = new List<Customer>();

            customers = db.Customers.ToList();

            return Json((
            from customer in customers
            orderby customer.Id descending
            select new[]{
                    customer.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
                    customer.FirstName,
                    customer.LastName,
                    customer.IsMale.ToString(),
                    customer.Address,
                    customer.Email,
                    customer.Phone,
                    customer.Country.Name,
                    customer.Note,
                    customer.Created.ToString()
                }).ToArray(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

I call this function in SetGridParam function but this action is not fired.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters `sidx` and `sord` are build dynamically based on the options `sortname` and `sortorder`. So if you really need to set the parameters you should use `setGridParam` with object having `sortname` and `sortorder` properties.

You use `fromdate` and `todate` as the values for `sidx` and `sord`. So I suspect that you need just send some *additional* parameter to the server and you try to use existing parameters. It's not the best way. I would recommend you to introduce *additional* parameters `fromDate` and `toDate` and to use `postData` parameters with functions as jqGrid option:

```js
// create jqGrid with additional postData parameter
$("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
    url: "/Home/GetFilterData",
    postData: {
        fromDate: function () {
            return $("#txtFrom").val();
        },
        toDate: function () {
            return $("#txtTo").val();
        }
    },
    ...
});

$("#Button1").click(function () {
    $("#jQGridDemo").trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);
});
```

You need additionally to change the names of parameters of the `GetFilterData` actions corresponds to the names of properties of `postData`:

```js
public JsonResult GetFilterData(string fromDate, string toDate)
{
    ...
}
```

I recommend you to read [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935) for additional information.

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath: You should append the text of your question with the code which you use to create the grid. For example if you use `loadonce: true` option then you will have to reset the value of `datatype` (to `"json"` or `"xml"` depend on what you use) **before** trigger `reloadGrid`.

Comment: Sorry for my incompleted comment. currently my loadonce property is true. I changed it to false. Now my action is fired in when reaload the grid.

Comment: @RageshPuthiyedath: In the case you have to reset `datatype`. The `$("#Button1").click` event handle should be for example `$("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid", [{page: 1}]);` (if you use `datatype: "json"` initially). The option `loadonce: true` **change** initial `datatype` to `"local"` after the first loading of data from the server. So to load it **from the server** one more time one have to reset initial `datatype` value before loading of the grid.

Comment: Thanks , It is also useful to bind custom value on jqgrid post

Comment: @MSTdev: You are welcome! Alternatively one can use `serializeGridData` callback.