# Maintain page number after reloading jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am updating a column value in jqgrid. After update i want to reload the grid and maintain page number with the updated data. For ex. if I am updating value in page 2. I want to reload the jggrid with updated value and page 2. I am using this code for reloading the grid.

```
function reload(){
   $("#table1").setGridParam({
    datatype : 'json',
    page : 1
}).trigger('reloadGrid');    
}
```

But it is reloading the grid with page 1.

I tried using

```
$("#table1").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true}]);
```

But it is not working.  Please provide a solution.

Comment: Did you try without `page: 1`?

Comment: @James: Yes I did. It reloads the grid with page 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `page` property of the options of `reloadGrid`:

```
$("#table1").trigger("reloadGrid", [{current:true, page:2}]);
```

see [the old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935).

Comment: it is maintaining page number 2 but not refreshing updated data into the grid It is not hitting server to populate the data.

Comment: @Neha: Probably you have *another* problem. If you use `loadonce: true` option then `datatype` will be changed from the initial value (`"json"` or `"xml"`) to `"local"`. So to reload the data *from the server* you have to use `$("#table1").jqGrid("setGridParam", {datatype: "json"}).trigger("reloadGrid", [{current: true, page: 2}]):`

Comment: I just posted a question here: http://bit.ly/1uCH1cz basically asking the same question, but this approach did not work for me, any idea what I might be missing?

Comment: @Tone: I don't think that it's the same problem. You want **don't reload the grid**. So no options of `reloadGrid` can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could get the `page` grid parameter and use it to tell the reload which page you would like to navigate to when the reload is complete.

```
function reload(){
   var page = $("#table1").getGridParam("page");    //Add this

   $("#table1").setGridParam({
       datatype : 'json',
       page : page            //Replace the '1' here
    }).trigger('reloadGrid');    
}
```

Comment: Where should this reload method be called? Thanks.