# jqGrid with large postData in setGridParam not working

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqgrid and want to post data while reloading the grid. I used below code while reloading

```
  var postData = {page:page,rows:rows,submitFlag:submitFlag,newRowMapData: newRowMapData,existingRowMapData:existingRowMapData};
  $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:null});
  $("#grid").jqGrid('setGridParam',{postData:postData});
  $("#grid").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

I am sending complete row data in post data. It works fine for two rows. But when I select more than two rows then data is not posted to server and grid dont reload. Is there any case that jqgrid postData can not post large data to server. So please suggest some solution on it.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what exactly you want to do. Typically one don't need ever use `setGridParam` because `getGridParam` returns you **the reference** to internal parameters of the grid and you can just modify the returned object. Resetting `postData` can't modify all data because some values will be set later during processing of `reloadGrid`. Moreover you don't included the code which shows in which form you use jqGrid. The only restriction in the size of posted data exist if you use `mtype: "GET"`: it's the standard restriction of URL length.

Comment: @Oleg Thank you very much Oleg for reply. You didnt undrestand the question but still your comment give me hint to solve my problem. Actaully I am working on struts2 jqgrid. Not a conventional one. So not very used it. I set requestType='POST' property in that and now its working. Can you just suggest how I set PostData for grid as you suggested my way is not proper.

Comment: You are welcome! I posted my answer and I would recommend you to read [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2928819/315935) too. It could be helpful for you. I just not sure where you can easy you the approach in struts2 or not.

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are no restriction in the size of posted data, but there are exist restriction of URL size if you use `mtype: "GET"` option (the parameters will be appended to the URL). So you should use `mtype: "POST"` option if you need to send large parameters in `postData`.

You can set `rowNum` parameters of jqGrid (not as properties of `postData` parameter) and to use `page` option of `reloadGrid` (see [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935)). In the case the code could be

```
$("#grid").jqGrid("setGridParam", {
    rowNum: rows,
    postData: {
        submitFlag: submitFlag,
        newRowMapData: newRowMapData,
        existingRowMapData: existingRowMapData
    }
}).trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: page }]);
```