# jqgrid - refresh a grid after an ajax file upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, jqgrid

How would I refresh a jqgrid based grid from outside of the grid itself? Within the code for a grid exists the option to call `reloadGrid`. However, I want to reload the grid after doing an ajax file upload, outside of the jqgrid code. How could I call `reloadGrid` in that context?

I realize I can completely reload the entire page with something like: `location.reload();` but that reloads the whole lot and puts me back to the first page of results for a grid and kind of defeats the purpose of using ajax to upload a file in the first place.

**Some code:**

reloadGrid is called from within jqgrid as follows:

`$("#thegrid").trigger("reloadGrid");`

but it does nothing when called from within my ajaxupload:

```
        onComplete: function(file, response) {
            if (response == 'success') {
                        //location.reload();
                        $("#thegrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
                    }else if (response == 'error') {
                        alert("Doh!");
                    }
```

If I uncomment `location.reload()`, the page reloads but with the trigger uncommented (as in the above example) nothing happens at all. So how do I reload this grid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no problem in using of `$("#thegrid").trigger("reloadGrid")` outside of jqGrid. Probably the problem is in relation between `onComplete` from the `ajaxupload` and `$("#thegrid")` at all.

For example you can define an external button on the same page as jqGrid with `<table>` element having id="thegrid" and use

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    if ($("#thegrid").length === 0) {
        alert("no element with id='thegrid' is found");
    }
    if ($.isFunction($("#thegrid").jqGrid) !== true) {
        alert("$('#thegrid') is not jqGrid");
    }
    var e = $("#thegrid").data("events");
    if (typeof(e) !== "undefined" && typeof(e.reloadGrid) !== "undefined") {
        $("#thegrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
    } else {
        alert("$('#thegrid') is not bound to 'reloadGrid' function");
    }
}
```

you will see the the code work without any alerts. You can include the same code inside of the `onComplete` handler of your ajaxupload.

To verify that 'reloadGrid' function work you can use [loadComplete](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents#list_of_events):

```
loadComplete: function() {
    alert("grid is loaded/reloaded");
}
```

**UPDATED**: Starting with jQuery 1.8 one should use `$._data($("#thegrid")[0], "events");` instead of `$("#thegrid").data("events")` to get the list of all events of the grid.

Comment: So I am reaching the trigger and loadComplete is firing, however I see no change in the grid. Could it be the fact that I have loadonce: true? Like, the grid is reloading but only with the local data it has on hand, which does not include the newly uploaded data? Hmmm... this seems likely, yes?

Comment: @rg88: Yes, it must be so if you use `loadonce:true`. From your question you don't included almost nothing about the jaGrid definition. If you use `loadonce:true` and want reload data from the server you should reset `datatype` back to `'json'` (After the first load the `datatype` are changed to the `'local'`). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3441839/jqgrid-reload-not-working/3442156#3442156 for example.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, do you know why setting loadonce:false would disable paging? with loadonce:true I get 3 pages of data (20 items per page) but with loadonce:false I only get one page of 20 items (though if I choose to display more items per page I can see them).

Comment: @rg88: If you don't use `loadonce:false` your server application should send back **only one page** of data back: the page which corresponds `page` input parameter, sorting parameters `sidx` and the sort direction `sord`. So you have to implement at least sorting and paging of data on the server side.

Answer (score 4):

Make a function of the code to load the jqgrid.
And unload the Jqgrid first, and call the previous function:

```
$("#thegrid").GridUnload();
Loadthegrid();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thx for the response though I don't quite follow. I assume GridUnload is a method available via jqGrid (yes?) but then this LoadtheGrid... that would just be the function of the code that I would create to load it in the first place? Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: GridUnload is indeed a method available via JqGrid. http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods&s[]=gridunload

Comment: And the Loadthegrid() is indeed your own function of the code that creates yourgrid in first place. You are understanding it correctly.

Comment: Thanks i can solve my problem quickly.. +1 for ans

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15859346/jqgrid-data-update-on-live-function-click-but-not-updating-data