# jqgrid colmodel title does not display UTF-8 characters properly

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqgrid displays garbled characters when I hover over the cell data for UTF-8(for example chinese) characters. But the grid displays the data correctly. Is it a limitation or is there a way to display the data correctly in the title/tooltip?

Head section has content-type set correctly.
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

Here is the screen shot of the issue...

[image: screenshot of the issue...]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry, but I couldn't reproduce the problem either with local data (see [the first demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnicodeTooltips.htm)) nor with JSON data (see [the second demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/UnicodeTooltips1.htm)). I have always the results like the following

[image]

Probably you used some very old web browsers or make some other errors. I hope that if you compare your code with my working demos you will find the reason of the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. I am using IE8 as my browser and even chrome has the same issue. But firefox displays the title correctly. Not sure if it is browser issue or am I missing anything. I have verified all my settings and they look similar to what you have in the demo. Please suggest...

Comment: I think it must be browser issue only because when I open your demos in IE8 and chrome I do not see the titles correctly where as firefox displays correctly. Is there a way to fix this? Thanks...

Comment: @varaprakash: You have probably the problem with the operation system and not with the web browser. **It works on my computer in all web browsers**: IE, Chrome, Opera, Firefox, Safari. I tested the demo even on Windows NT 4 SP6 in the Internet Explorer 6 and it works. I suppose that not all fonts are installed correctly on your computer.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! Sorry for the late response as I was off the hook with my releases. Could be fonts issue but I am not sure why it is working in firefox but not in IE and Chrome :(

Comment: Could you please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493129/jqgrid-does-not-submit-reset-page-value-on-triggering-reload) when you get a chance. Thanks...

Comment: @varaprakash: In every web browser you can configure which font should be used to display elements of web page like tooltip. I think that IE and Chrome on your computer use the font which is not installed with all code pages. Which operation system you use? Do you tried to make the same tests on another computer? I tried to answer on your new question, but you don't posted enough information and I have now not so much time.

Comment: Oleg: Thanks for the inputs. I am using win xp with sp3. Initially I had problem with grid data as well, then I changed the font for chinese after that it started displaying properly in the grid but not tooltip though. I have tried in other's system as well but the same issue. Regarding configuration of font for tooltip, did you mean by going to appearance tab -> advanced -> Tooltip -> font?? That does not have any language script option like IE -> Tool -> Internet Options had. Not sure if there is any other way to do it. Please let me know if it's possible to set, I will try that as well.

Comment: @varaprakash: It't difficult to say what is wrong exactly on your computer/computers, but on all computers where I tested my demo (XP SP3 + IE8 or even NT4 SP6 with IE6) the tooltips was displayed correctly. So I supposed that on your computers no East Asian languages installed. Open "Regional and Language Options" in "Control Panel" and verify on the "Languages" tab that all checkboxs  on from the "Supplemental language support" group are installed. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_install_languages.mspx?mfr=true) for example.

Comment: Oleg: thanks again. Yes I googled and saw this link after I replied to your post. I do not have East Asian languages installed. But I am very curious to know how come Firefox displays the data if those characters were not installed on my PC. FYI, my FF version is 9.0 I am going crazy :)

Comment: @varaprakash: Some fonts could be installed together with Firefox or some other software which you used. I installed on all computer support for all languages always.